# Making a quiver plot from .dat files

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Hi I am trying to make a quiver (vector field) plot from data that is stored in .dat files.  I have 4 .dat files which are 1D arrays, one for the x axis, y axis, f(x,y) along x and f(x,y) along y.

Note, I am able to construct a quiver plot without importing data from .dat files, I just followed this basic example [here](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/matplotlib/auto_examples/plot_quiver_ex.html).

However, I am unable to apply this basic example to my example in which I need to import the data from .dat files.  My code is below, I am not getting any error messages but I am getting a blank quiver plot.  Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n=12

data0 = np.genfromtxt('xaxis.dat')
data1 = np.genfromtxt('yaxis.dat')
data2 = np.genfromtxt('fx.dat')
data3 = np.genfromtxt('fy.dat')

x  = data0[0]
y  = data1[0]
fx = data2[0]
fy = data3[0]

plt.axes([0.025, 0.025, 0.95, 0.95])
plt.quiver(x,y,fx,fy, alpha=.5)
plt.quiver(x,y,fx,fy,edgecolor='k',facecolor='none', linewidth=.5)

plt.xlim(-1,n)
plt.xticks(())
plt.ylim(-1,n)
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

Comment: Notice the shape of the `X`, `Y`, `U` and `V`from your example: they are 2D arrays. Are the ones you import also 2D? Try to remove the `x=data0[0]` and see how it goes. Nevertheless the quiver expects 2D arrays and for each row `i` and column `j` will retrieve the x value from `X[i,j]`, the y value from `Y[i,j]` and so on and so forth...

Comment: @berna1111 Thanks for your help.  My .dat files are all 1 column arrays, so 1D arrays.  I made a separate .dat file for each of the 4 inputs that Quiver takes.   Do you suggest combining x,y into one 2D array?  Then I wouldn't have 4 inputs so I am unsure how to do that.  THanks!

Comment: I believed you needed to have something like `X=[[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2]]` and `Y=[[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]`, with `U=[...,[...,fx(X[i,j],Y[i,j]),...],...]` and  `V=[...,[...,fy(X[i,j],Y[i,j]),...],...]`, but it seems you can have all arrays 1D and it should work, according to [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.quiver)

Comment: I tried to emulate your code again and found a way to make an empty plot without raising an error: if the `genfromtxt` doesn't read the data right, it fills the arrays with `NaN`'s. So make sure your arrays contain numbers and not just `NaN`'s everywhere. Make sure you specify the right separator between numbers and that you use the correct decimal separator inside those numbers.

Comment: @berna1111 How did you get it to make a plot?   You used 4 1D arrays? I do not have any NaN, I have checked for this.  I constructed 4 simple arrays and it still will not work with the code above.  What do you suggest doing?  Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: I will edit the answer bellow to include my attempts to replicate the problem. But I've just noticed that you have `plt.xlim(-1,n)` and `plt.ylim(-1,n)`, are you sure your x and y values are within that interval? Because it might be that your are just looking at an empty part of the graph.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that would be really helpful.  Once I can understand what you did and all I am going to accept the answer.  The x,y values are within that interval however I omitted that from my code since its not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [example for the quiver plot](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/matplotlib/auto_examples/plot_quiver_ex.html) you provided all `X`, `Y`, `U` and `V` are 2D arrays, with shape `(n,n)`.

In your example you are importing an array of values for `x`, `y`, `fx` and `fy`, and then selecting only the first line with `[0]`.

When using the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n=3 # number of points, changed it

data0 = np.genfromtxt('xaxis.dat')
data1 = np.genfromtxt('yaxis.dat')
data2 = np.genfromtxt('fx.dat')
data3 = np.genfromtxt('fy.dat')

x  = data0[0]
y  = data1[0]
fx = data2[0]
fy = data3[0]

plt.axes([0.025, 0.025, 0.95, 0.95]) # position of bottom left point of graph inside window and its size
plt.quiver(x,y,fx,fy, alpha=.5) # draw inside of arrows, half transparent
plt.quiver(x,y,fx,fy,edgecolor='k',facecolor='none', linewidth=.5) # draw contours of arrows

plt.xlim(-1,n) # left and right most values in the x axis
plt.xticks(()) # remove the numbers from the x axis
plt.ylim(-1,n) # ...
plt.yticks(()) # ...

plt.show()
```

I get:
[image: only one point]
With `0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2` in xaxis.dat and fx.dat, `0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2` in yaxis.dat and `1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3` in fy.dat.
If I just remove the `[0]` from the arrays assignment, I get:
[image: all points]
with all points shown.

One change I would make is to use `plt.xlim(min(x)-1,max(x)+1)` and `plt.ylim(min(y)-1,max(y)+1)`, to ensure you get to view the right area of the graph. For instance, if I make all four arrays equal to `np.random.rand(10)` (a 1D array with 10 random elements between 0 and 1), I get:
[image: random points]

### Notes on array shape

The `plt.quiver` will also accept the arrays in the format:

```
x  = [0, 1, 2] # 1D array (list, actually...)
y  = [0, 1, 2]
fx = [[0, 1, 2],
      [0, 1, 2],
      [0, 1, 2]] # 2D array
fy = [[0, 0, 0],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [2, 2, 2]]
```

[image]
But will not mesh automatically if all arrays are 1D (in which case it will repeat `x` and `y` without the correct structure:

```
fx = np.array(fx).flatten()
fy = np.array(fy).flatten()
```

[image]

So either have:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
fx = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
      [0, 1, 2, 3],
      [0, 1, 2, 3]]
fy = [[4, 4, 4, 4],
      [5, 5, 5, 5],
      [6, 6, 6, 6]]
```

and let `plt` do the mesh for you, or have all arrays with the same shape and `plt.quiver` will get each arrow's position and components from them per index:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]
fx = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
fy = [4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

### Previous answer (wrong)

[first two paragraphs]...

This means you probably noticed `genfromtxt` returns a 2D array (as it is able to import several columns from a single file, so the returned array will mimic the 2D structure of your file if nothing else is told), making `data0[0]` the first line on your document xaxis.dat.

**EDIT:** the sentence below is erroneous, [plt.quiver](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.quiver) can receive 1D arrays, just in the right shape.

However the `quiver` expects 2D arrays, from where it will retrieve the values for each point: for point `i,j` the position will be `(X[i,j], Y[i,j])` and the arrow will be `(U[i,j], V[i,j])`.

If you have the repeated values for x and y in the file like this:

- xaxis.dat:

  0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2
- yaxix.dat:

  0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2

You can just [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) all four of your arrays to (# points in x, # points in y) and it should work out.

If you don't you will have to use something similar to [`np.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) (or [`np.meshgrid`](http://louistiao.me/posts/numpy-mgrid-vs-meshgrid/)) to make a valid combination of `X` and `Y` arrays, and format `fx` and `fy` accordingly.

Comment: Also, my numbers do not have repeated values and such, so I will have to use np.mgrid which I am unsure of how to.  THanks again!

Comment: Thanks! I will go through all of this and if I have questions I will let you know ASAP.  Thanks again for the thorough explanation.

Comment: How can I make the size of the arrows very small?  Now that I have this code working, I will tell you my .dat files have about a hundred thousands points in each, compared to 9 as in this example.  So I want my quiver plot to show a few hundred thousand arrows.  Is there a way to make the arrows smaller?    Otherwise my plot now has so many points I cannot resolve anything. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025306/how-to-use-matplotlib-quiver-scale)

Comment: Thanks.  How can I format fx, fy accordingly?  As I said I do not have repeated values in my arrays, so I am having a lot of trouble meshing the grid.  How can I do this?  I can mesh the grid if I am working with known functions, but I get confused now since I'm importing .dat files and I do not know how to mesh them.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you have something like: `x  = [0, 1, 2, 3]; y  = [4, 5, 6]; fx = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]; fy = [4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]`, you can use `fx = np.reshape(fx, (len(y), len(x)))` and `fy = np.reshape(fy, ((len(y), len(x)))` and let `plt.quiver(x, y, fx, fy, ...)` do the meshing for you. If you want to repeat `x` and `y` (as `list`!) you can also use `old_len_y = len(y); old_len_x = len(x); x = x * old_len_y; y = y * old_len_x`. If you have random `x` and `y` values for each point, every array should have the same length and shape (`fx = np.array(fx).flatten()`).

Comment: Just noticed, the `old_len_y = len(y); old_len_x = len(x); x = x * old_len_y; y = y * old_len_x` will not work as the `y` values will be out of order. Use `x, y = np.meshgrid(x,y)` instead.