# Python - pyplot.quiver(X, Y, U, V) not plotting expected result

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

When attempting to plot vectors using the quiver method in the pyplot library, I receive an unexpected and incorrect result.
While debugging, I printed out the required arrays to the console and received :

```
X = [0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 40, 40, 40, 80, 80, 80, 80, 120, 120, 120, 120] # X-coordinate
Y = [0, 40, 80, 120, 0, 40, 80, 120, 0, 40, 80, 120, 0, 40, 80, 120] # Y-coordinate
UN = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1] # X-component
VN = [0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1] # Y-component
```

The arrays above are plotted using the following snippet of code :

```
plot = plt.figure()
plt.quiver(X, Y, UN, VN, color='Teal', headlength=7)

plt.title('Quiver Plot, Single Colour')
plt.show(plot)
```

Output:

[image: Quiver Plot]

As you can see we expected the vectors to be max 1 unit long (0 or 1) and still we receive incorrect (longer) vectors on our plot.

Comment: Is it a [scaling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025306/how-to-use-matplotlib-quiver-scale) issue?

Comment: By the way, the largest vectors you have are (-1,-1) and their length is the square root of two (1.414...)

Comment: I deleted my answer and added something and undeleted it, I am not sure if you get any notification for an undeleted message, hence this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `scale_units='xy'` and `scale=1` :

code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 40, 40, 40, 80, 80, 80, 80, 120, 120, 120, 120] # X-coordinate
Y = [0, 40, 80, 120, 0, 40, 80, 120, 0, 40, 80, 120, 0, 40, 80, 120] # Y-coordinate
UN = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1] # X-component
VN = [0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1] # Y-component

plot = plt.figure()
plt.quiver(X, Y, UN, VN, color='Teal', scale_units ='x',scale=1)

plt.title('Quiver Plot, Single Colour')
plt.xlim(-10,130)
plt.ylim(-10,130)
plt.show(plot)
```

result:

[image]

They are there but they are actually pretty small. Here's the zoomed version on the top left one :

[image]

Comment: Still no clue why they showed up so big in certain spots solely because of the scaling, but it worked! Thankyou!